# to call a div or Section from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a website called pipocaplayfm.com and trying to create a front page with the already existing content.

I have a page called main.html and in it I will gather all this content (ex: top five, rhythms and etc)

I found some things in English and Portuguese, but since I'm a beginner in programming, I prefer to get help.

I've seen a lot of people quote "it does with jquery" But I have no idea how to start.

The site: www.pipocaplayfm.com

Page that will receive these divs or Section: main.html

Example page to get a div or Section can be: www.pipocaplayfm.com/genre/rock

Answer (score 0):

theres a million ways to do it, but most likely they will make an ajax call to an API, to pull that information from another site's api... or they will have their own database and make a call to a custom API they write and hosted server side with node.js

Comment: jQuery Selectors
 is one of the practical solutions, but I can not. The idea is simple: copy a DIV and paste it into another page.

Comment: 'jquery selectors' is just a javascript library - it is a syntactical sweetener - it just makes pushing data to places and pulling data from other places easier. 

you will need a javascript to do the logic.  and most likely you will need an ajax call. Whether you use jquery in any of those things is not relevant.